# How does autoload cookie work on non defun form

Tags: elisp, package, hooks

sometimes I see a "unkosher" use of autoload coookie, for example:

```
;;;###autoload
(add-hook 'some-hook 'some-fun)
```

How will the above work? Will it add a hook just by being installed (as autoloads get loaded automatically)?

Comment: (Just something to keep in mind for those who use this in packages.) The autoloading of some non-defun forms changed a bit since Emacs 24.1 (which is what most packages support). In particular, something that's a macro call or a progn will be handled differently depending on the emacs version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the answer yourself, by using `i autoload` in the Elisp manual. That takes you to node [`Autoload`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Autoload.html#Autoload) (funny about that).

This part of that node gives you the answer:

> The same magic comment can copy any kind of form into `loaddefs.el`.
>   The form following the magic comment is copied verbatim, *except* if it
>   is one of the forms which the autoload facility handles specially
>   (e.g., by conversion into an `autoload` call).  The forms which are not
>   copied verbatim are the following:...

That means that your `(add-hook 'some-hook 'some-fun)` is executed when the file is loaded, and it is also added to `loaddefs.el`.

If the form is on the same line as the autoload cookie then it is just copied to `loaddefs.el`.  If on the same line, the form is effectively commented out, so it has no effect when the file is loaded. From the same node:

> You can also use a magic comment to execute a form at build time
>   *without* executing it when the file itself is loaded.  To do this,
>   write the form *on the same line* as the magic comment.  Since it is in
>   a comment, it does nothing when you load the source file; but `M-x update-file-autoloads` copies it to `loaddefs.el`, where it is executed
>   while building Emacs.